# PRISM gridded (.bil) file to county(.csv) conversion

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I want to convert PRISM gridded temperature data from .bil to US county-level in CSV format. All together I need to do this for all daily files from 1981-2019. I am writing the following Python code inside the QGIS Python console to convert files for just one year:

```
import processing 
import os
import re

pth = "...path of input files..."
out_pth = "...path for output files..."

f_list = os.listdir(pth)
r = re.compile(".+bil$")
f_list = list(filter(r.match, f_list))
out_list = [i.replace("bil", "csv") for i in f_list]

for i in range(len(f_list)):
    processing.run("qgis:zonalstatistics", { 'COLUMN_PREFIX' : '_', 'INPUT_VECTOR' : '...parth to input county layer.../cb_2018_us_county_500k.shp', 'INPUT_RASTER' : pth+f_list[i], 'OUTPUT' : out_pth+out_list[i], 'RASTER_BAND' : 1, 'STATISTICS' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] })
```

When I run this code, QGIS just freezes. Not sure if the code is wrong, or my computer is not powerful enough to run this code.

Comment: Have you confirmed that it runs on a single file first? If not I'd suggest testing the `processing.run(...)` with hard coded paths for one file outside the loop and see what you get.

Comment: Not working. I tries running single file manually using the Zonal Statistics algorithm ....I keep getting error that field _count already exists.

Comment: My guess is that your county input shapefile already has a `_count` field in it.